# Hover div (with a border and padding) over the center of a canvas element?

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

I want the `div` to be exactly in the center horizontally. I've tried this:

```
var div = document.createElement();
div.textContent = 'Hello World!';
div.className = 'button';
div.style.position = 'absolute';
div.style.left = (0.5 * canvas.width) + canvas.offsetLeft + 'px';
```

The class `button` is defined as follows:

```
.button{
    color : black;
    padding : 10px;
    border : solid black 3px;
    border-radius : 10px;
    overflow : none;
}
```

Obviously, there's a problem with defining the pixels it is from the left to be exactly half of the canvas: The text is of a variable width. If I could find the width of the text, I could just divide it by 2 and subtract it from what I'm currently assigning to the `left` property.

I've tried just making a `div` with an `absolute` position, which hovers right above the canvas and aligning all text to the `center` within that `div`, but that didn't work either.

- [First attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/SFR82/)
- [Second attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/YRmht/)

Please try to give your answers in Plain JavaScript, without using any library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/CgYTn/1/) is an example of how I would solve the problem..

```
var cvsHeight = cvs.height,
    cvsWidth = cvs.width;

var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
var offsetX = cvs.offsetLeft,
    offsetY = cvs.offsetTop;

foo.style.top = offsetY + (cvsHeight / 2) - (foo.offsetHeight / 2) + "px";
foo.style.left = offsetX + (cvsWidth / 2) - (foo.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
```

basically you take half the height and width of the floating object and subtract that from half the height and width of the canvas... then add in the x and y offset (where the canvas sits on the page) and BAM your done!

Comment: just noticed typo in my example.. in the fiddle as well. `foo.style.left = offsetY ...` should be `foo.style.left = offsetX `

Answer (score 1):

Use `ctx.measureText`, after setting `ctx.font` correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/SFR82/2/.

I also suggest using `border` in CSS correctly, like `3px solid black`.

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.font = "12pt Times New Roman"; // same as <div> font; this is default for me

var textSize = ctx.measureText(text);

...

div.style.left = 0.5 * canvas.offsetWidth // half canvas width
    + canvas.offsetLeft                   // plus left position
    - (textSize.width / 2)                // minus half of text width
    - 10                                  // minus padding
    - 3                                   // minus border size
    + 'px';
```

Comment: I'd prefer having the function being dynamic and hence not having to actually type the actual values of the padding and the border size, but +1 for `ctx.measureText`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this line

```
div.style.left = (0.5 * canvas.width + canvas.offsetLeft - (div.clientWidth / 2)) + 'px';
```

and the equivalent for height, but only after you've added the div to the DOM.